# Push C# DateTime to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to push a C# `DateTime` to a javascript array. Ideally, I'd like it converted to a string. I've tried multiple different approaches but none have worked. The continual error I get is that I'm missing a `)` which I can't make much sense of.

I declare a local js variable to hold the values:

```
var startDates = [];
```

I've tried:

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            @:startDates.push(Date(@d.StartDate.Date));
        }
```

and

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            @:startDates.push(Date(@d.StartDate));
        }
```

and

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            @:startDates.push(@d.StartDate);
        }
```

and

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            @:startDates.push(Date(@d.StartDate.ToString()));
        }
```

and

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            @:startDates.push(new Date(@d.StartDate.Date));
        }
```

and

```
        @foreach (var d in Model.Items)
        {
            var date = d.StartDate.ToString();
            @:startDates.push(date);
        }
```

each results in the same JavaScript runtime error: I'm missing a `)`.

I'm also using a similar method for floats that works just fine:

```
        @foreach (var v in Model.Items)
        {
            @:values.push(parseFloat(@v.Value));
        }
```

An example of the rendered JavaScript is:

```
            startDates.push(new Date(1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
            startDates.push(new Date(2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
            startDates.push(new Date(3/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
            startDates.push(new Date(4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
            startDates.push(new Date(5/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
            startDates.push(new Date(6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM));
```

Comment: try changing `Date()` to `new Date()`

Comment: @333 I've tried that as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the rendered JavaScript?

Comment: @KevinBoucher I've added a sample of the js in the edited question

Comment: You need to wrap the values with quotes like this: new Date('1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by the value passed into the `new Date()` constructor.

It should have quotes around the date value: `new Date('1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM')`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This works. Is there a way to parse the `Date` to a short date (i.e. no time)? I tried `@:startDates.push(new Date('@d.StartDate.Date'));` but this still renders the long date format

Comment: Indeed it needs quotes, but even then it may not work depending on your visitors timezone. See here for a foolproof way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835394/1220550

Comment: IMHO it's unfortunate Date wasn't named DateTime.  When strings are parsed they're assumed to be UTC which can lead to confusion.  From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can also specify local date using ```new Date(year, month, day)```, but beware month is zero based (which is also unintuitive).